# Does time dilate according to string theory, or do the extra dimensions simply make things take longer?

Tags: spacetime, string-theory, time-dilation

Apologies for the "unscientific" way of asking this. I have been trying to look this up but haven't gotten a clear answer.

In general relativity, it's said that time itself stretches in the presence of energy.

Is this true in String Theory as well? As best as I can tell, the answer is "no". Rather, because of the extra spacial dimensions and how energy moves through it, things simply appear to take longer.

Is that a correct assessment of time in String Theory?

Comment: I can't answer you whether string theory models gravitational time dilation (the effect in which time moves more slowly closer to very massive objects), but I can tell you with certainty that it does model kinetic time dilation (the effect in which time moves more slowly for objects traveling in speeds close to the speed of light). Quantum field theory does models kinetic time dilation, which follows from the fact that all equations of motion are required to be Lorentz invariant, and string theory is supposed to reduce to quantum field theory in some specific limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String theory can predict the geometries of General Relativity, that is why there is an interest in the subject.

> [On distance scales larger than the string scale,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) a string looks just like an ordinary particle, with its mass, charge, and other properties determined by the vibrational state of the string. In string theory, one of the many vibrational states of the string corresponds to the graviton, a quantum mechanical particle that carries gravitational force. Thus string theory is a theory of quantum gravity.

Quantum gravity is the quantization of GR so the same mathematics hold.

As in all physics theories time is one of the four observable coordinates . In special relativity and general relativity, how time is defined in different inertial frames produces the effect of time dilation. As string theories at the dimensions we are able to measure reduce to the standard model dimensions of particle physics and to the variables of general relativity, there is no change in the effect of time dilation. "On distance scales larger than the string scale" :particle physics is on distance scales larger than the string scale.

If one is  are trying to think what happens at smaller distances, it cannot be seen in experiments, and it will depend on the specific string model how the mathematics treats time at those unmeasurable dimension

Comment: I apologize but I don't understand this answer. In string theory does time actually dialate or is time constant but propagating through the additional dimensions make time appear to slow?

Comment: edited comments content into the answer